# .NET Framework and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net

When i start to open a Visual C# windows form application, there is an option for choosing .NET Framework in New Project Windows. My question is i built some application in .NET Framework 4.5.2 which i can't run it on other computer because of .NET Compatibility. If i choose a lower .NET Framework during selection of new project windows form application and build the app in lower .NET version, can i run it on system having low .NET framework version.

[image]

Comment: I'm going to be completely honest here, I really don't understand what you want or even what you are asking for that matter. Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: On the other machine that you say you can not run the application, any reasons not to install .net 4.5.2? https://www.microsoft.com/nb-no/download/details.aspx?id=42642

Comment: Yes, if you build it for the framework version on the other computer, it will run on the other computer. However if you have used any of the framework 4.5.2 feature in your code, it won't build in a lower framework

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and if you install a higher .net version on your machine you can run the application too.

Search the Microsoft site for .NET downloads.

Answer (score 0):

When a new .Net Framework is published by Microsoft it contains new tools so if you do not require to use any of new tools you can choose lower versions of .Net framework. 
But, when you want to run your program in another machine the destination machine  should have the compatible .Net framework. So, you should install it ().Net framework first and then run your application.

use link below to download .Net framework

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=.net%20framework

Comment: thanks. actually i was just as a learner to c# try to build a small app for my workplace where they have installed POS embedded windows which can't support .net framework more than 3.5.

Comment: @ziakhan then you can configure to .Net framework 3.5 or less